# Kotlin: Can't parse regular expression containing multiple back slashes - Why do I have a "Unclosed group"?

Tags: regex, parsing, kotlin

I am trying to match the anchor link that is "triple-escaped" in this string example:

`blablabla some text <a href=\\\"#anchor\\\"> some more text`

This is my regular expression:

`href=(\\\\\\)(\"#.*)(\\\\\\)\"`

If I test it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) it works, but I need to do this filtering in Kotlin, which I thought I could do like this:

```
fun findEscapedAnchors(text: String): String {
    val pattern = "href=(\\\\\\)(\"#.*)(\\\\\\)\""
    val regex = pattern.toRegex()
    val matches = regex.find(text)

    // do something with the matches
}
```

First of all, if I paste this String into my code (in Android Studio), it gets auto-escaped even more, but it doesn't work. If I edit it to match the above String, it complains that there's an unclosed group. I thought I could maybe put it in triple quotations to not have to escape characters, but that also failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out myself: A raw string (triple quotations) was indeed the way to go, but `Regex` apparently still needs the character escapes in the string. Before, I had them removed, because I thought that's how raw strings work, but I was wrong. So it works now with this:

```
val regex = """href=(\\\\\\)(\"#.*)(\\\\\\)\"""".toRegex()
```